# Let X|Y = m ∼ Poisson(m), if Y ∼ gamma(2, 1). Evaluate E[X] and Var[X].

Tags: statistics

Let X|Y = m ∼ Poisson(m), if Y ∼ gamma(2, 1). Evaluate E[X]
and Var[X].

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the formulas:

$$E(X)=E(E(X|Y))\\
Var(X)=E(Var(X|Y))+Var(E(X|Y))$$